# Swagger Swashbuckle Asp.NET Core: show details about every enum is used

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have the following enum:

```cs
public enum TicketQuestionType
{
    General = 1,
    Billing = 2,
    TMS = 3,
    HOS = 4,
    DeviceManagement = 5
}
```

and model class:

```cs
public class TicketCreateApi
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public TicketQuestionType QuestionType { get; set; } = TicketQuestionType.General;
    public TicketType Type { get; set; } = TicketType.Problem;
    public TicketStatus Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.New;
    public TicketPriority Priority { get; set; } = TicketPriority.Normal;
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<string> Attachments { get; set; }
    public int? DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int? DriverId { get; set; }
}
```

my API method uses it:

```cs
Task<IActionResult> Create(TicketCreateApi model);
```

Swagger generates the following:

[image]

and this:

[image]

so, we can see only default value and no way to see available list of enum (names and values).
I would like to show it. How to do it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> we can see only default value and no way to see available list of enum
> (names and values). I would like to show it. How to do it?

To display the enums as strings in swagger, you configure the JsonStringEnumConverter, adding the following line in ConfigureServices :

```
        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

The output as below:

[image]

If you want to display the enums as stings and int values, you could try to create a EnumSchemaFilter to change the schema. code as below:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            model.Enum.Clear();
            Enum.GetNames(context.Type)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(name => model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString($"{Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(context.Type, name))} = {name}")));
        }
    }
}
```

Configure the SwaggerGen to use above ShemaFilter.

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "ToDo API",
                Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "Shayne Boyer",
                    Email = string.Empty,
                    Url = new Uri("https://twitter.com/spboyer"),
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "Use under LICX",
                    Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license"),
                }
            });
              
            c.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
        });
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: JsonStringEnumConverter affects the way the entire system handles enumerators, making them receive string instead of integer.

EnumSchemaFilter breaks the functionality of calls with enumerators through the swagger.

Comment: Clean and easy implementation. Better than add the attribute in each Enum +1. Works perfectly in .Net 6 Core

Answer (score 1):

I tried EnumSchemaFilter. I got some error every time i submited the request.
Because the serialize enum string to int

I used this code block and i hope it works

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
                    .AddJsonOptions(
                        opts =>
                        {
                            var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
                            opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
                        });
```